# TikZ - use non-Tikz command to layout part of picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, nesting

I'm using a package (`semantic.sty`) that draws something semi-complicated using LaTeX (not TikZ).  I would like to draw part of a TikZ picture using the same command, with parts of the TikZ picture embedded inside.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantic,tikz}

% \newcommand\tnode[2]{\tikz\node[anchor=text,inner sep=0](#1){$#2$};}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(C){$
\inference{
    \inference{
        A & B
%         A & \tnode{B}{B}
    }{A \wedge B} &
    \inference{
        C & D
    }{C \wedge D}
%     }{\tnode{CandD}{C \wedge D}}
}{(A \wedge B) \wedge (C \wedge D)}
$};
\node(N)[draw,above=.5in] at (C.north) {N};
\node(E)[draw,right=.5in] at (C.east) {E};
\node(S)[draw,below=.5in] at (C.south) {S};
\node(W)[draw,left=.5in] at (C.west) {W};
% \tikzset{every path/.style={draw,very thick}}
% \path[red] (N) to[out=-90,in=90] (B);
% \path[green] (E) to[out=180,in=0] (CandD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

produces everything but the colored lines in

[image: latex output with mocked up lines]

I would like to draw the mocked-up colored lines connecting nodes to parts of the tree, and possibly also turn some things in the tree into TikZ nodes (so I can add background colors, borders, etc.).

The most tempting way I can think of is to embed `\tikz\node`s inside the tree (commented code above), but this doesn't work:

[image: latex output with incorrect lines]

Some other answers I've read suggest replacing nested `\tikz`/`tikzpicture`s with `fit`, but this doesn't seem to work in my case because the `\tikz`s need to be embedded deep inside a LaTeX command.  Less importantly, I think the code for embedded `\tikz`s is more user-friendly.

A more drastic solution would be to reimplement the LaTeX drawing command in TikZ, but this would be the least desirable option for me.

Question: what would be the cleanest way to achieve this, preferably using syntax resembling the above (commented-out) code?

Comment: Have you tried using the `remember picture` option with `\node`? Also, are you trying to connect the red line/curve to the letter `B` and the green line/curve to the letter `D`?

Comment: Uhh, TikZ pictures inside nodes inside TikZ pictures equal bad idea because options get inherited. — You need to add `remember picture` to the outer `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting TikZ pictures is usually a bad idea as options from the outer picture get inherited by the inner one. In your example, it suffices to add `remember picture` to the outer TikZ picture (which is inherited by the inner one) so that the one recognizes the other one.

A better approach though offers the `tikzmark` library accessible via the CTAN package [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) which provides us with

```
\subnode[<options>]{<name>}{<content>}
```

which creates a pseudo-node around text.

Be aware that the `tikzmark` library needs at least two compilations to work correctly.

---

I have also used the `positioning` library and thte `node distance` key to provide a more consistent positioning of the compass nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}
\newcommand\tnode[2]{\subnode{#1}{$#2$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, node distance=.5in]
\node(C){$
  \inference{
    \inference{A & \tnode{B}{B}}{A \wedge B}               &
    \inference{C &            D}{\tnode{CandD}{C \wedge D}}
  }{(A \wedge B) \wedge (C \wedge D)}
$};
\node[draw, above=of C] (N) at (C.north) {N};
\node[draw, right=of C] (E) at (C.east) {E};
\node[draw, below=of C] (S) at (C.south) {S};
\node[draw, left= of C] (W) at (C.west) {W};
\tikzset{every path/.style={draw,very thick}}
\path[red]   (N) to[out=-90,in=90] (B);
\path[green] (E) to[out=180,in=0]  (CandD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possibility using `\tikzmark` to place some marks at the desired locations; the options `remember picture, overlay` allow then to use the marks with other elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,semantic,tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node(C){$
\inference{
    \inference{
        A & \tikzmark{b}B
    }{A \wedge B} &
    \inference{
        C & D
    }{C \wedge D\tikzmark{d}}
}{(A \wedge B) \wedge (C \wedge D)}
$};
\node(N)[draw,above=.5in] at (C.north) {N};
\node(E)[draw,right=.5in] at (C.east) {E};
\node(S)[draw,below=.5in] at (C.south) {S};
\node(W)[draw,left=.5in] at (C.west) {W};

\draw[red] (N) to[out=-90,in=90] ([xshift=5pt,yshift=10pt]b.north);
\draw[green] (E) to[out=180,in=-20] ([yshift=2pt]d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]